# How to stop recursive pagination in S3 Paginator

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the S3 directory structure like this

```
bucket 
|___ base_path
        |__ data1.csv
        |__ data2.csv
        |__ processed/
               |_ data1.csv
               |_ data2.csv
```

On reading the data using boto3 and paginator like the code below I don't want the files in `processed` folder to be fetched, but aws `Paginator` by default returns all the files under `base_path`

```
def load_irt_files():
    paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects")
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Prefix=f"base_path/data/")
    file_name_list = []
    for page in page_iterator:
        file_name_list.extend([obj["Key"] for obj in page["Contents"]])
```

**Expected Output**

```
["base_path/data1.csv", 
"base_path/data2.csv"]
```

**Current Output**

```
["base_path/data1.csv", 
"base_path/data2.csv",
"base_path/processed/data1.csv"
"base_path/processed/data2.csv"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `Delimiter='/'` then the results will be limited to only the specified folder.

This also results in a list of `CommonPrefixes` being returned, which lists the sub-folders that are available.