# How to list all csv files from an s3 bucket using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the below code that pulls in all the folder names as well as file names from specific S3 bucket. How to modify this so it can read only files that ends with ".csv" and not all the folder  names?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    bucket_name = "dump"
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
    files = response.get("Contents")
    for file in files:
        print(f"file_name: {file['Key']}")
```

Current output:

```
file_name: 2023/
file_name: 2023/Feb/
file_name: 2023/Feb/file1.csv
file_name: 2023/Jan/
file_name: 2023/Jan/file2.csv
file_name: 2023/Mar/
file_name: 2023/Mar/file3.csv
```

However, I want to list only thecsv files. So I want the output to be:

```
file_name: 2023/Feb/file1.csv
file_name: 2023/Jan/file2.csv
file_name: 2023/Mar/file3.csv
```

How to do that? I tried "endswith" but it's not working. Any help?

Comment: This just upsets me because it brings back all memories of why `boto3` is garbage. What it's doing is recursing the file paths by default, so you actively have to stop that. Then you have `list_objects_v2()`, which is fantastic design. Layer on top that it truncates at 1000 results because, reasons.

Comment: Because of the arbitrary reason it can't list more than 1000 results, your first priority should be to stop it recursing directories

Comment: Agree. In my specific case I don't have more than 50 result sets

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63275786/4799172 is the first part

Comment: @roganjosh I'm trying to do a one time listing of files from s3 and my bucket size is definitely not more than 50 items. So resursing folder stoppage is not too helpful here

Comment: `[item for item in s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name).get("Contents") if item.endswith('.csv')]`

Comment: I no longer have access to S3 to test that and it's super-fragile if it even works, based on what I said in my first comments

Answer (score 1):

Here, I would prefer using resources which provides a higher level of abstraction compare to the client methods. You can use the `filter` method of `Bucket` resource and optionally specify the `Prefix`  if you want to limit your search to a specific folder

```
def handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('dump')

    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='2023'):
        if obj.key.endswith('.csv'):
            pass
```